# How do I disable error messages when a substitution fails inside a Vim function?

Tags: vim

I have a dead simple function in Vim that cleans source code by calling :retab and removing trailing whitespace, like so:

```
:function CodeClean()
:  retab
:  %s/\s\+$//
:endfunction
```

If my source code has no trailing whitespace, I get the following error messages:

```
Error detected while processing function CodeClean:
line    2:
E486: Pattern not found: \s\+$
```

So for my purposes, I either need to tell the substitution command that match errors should be silent, or tell the function invocation to ignore errors, or something else. How do I surpress error messages on substitution failure?

Answer (score 14):

You can try add the 'e' option to the substitute or use `:silent!` as a prefix to any command

```
:%s/\s\+$//e
:silent! %s/\s\+$//
```

*Notice:*

> You'll need to use :silent!, as :silent only removes normal messages
>   (and only up to the first error, subsequent messages will all be
>   shown)---*comment of @Marth, Thanks!*

Comment: You'll need to use `:silent!`, as `:silent` only removes normal messages (and only up to the first error, subsequent messages will all be shown).

Comment: This also needs to happen for macros.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `e` flag, i.e `:%s/\s\+$//e`.

From `:h s_flags` :

```
[e]     When the search pattern fails, do not issue an error message and, in
        particular, continue in maps as if no error occurred.  This is most
        useful to prevent the "No match" error from breaking a mapping.  Vim
        does not suppress the following error messages, however:
            Regular expressions can't be delimited by letters
            \ should be followed by /, ? or &
            No previous substitute regular expression
            Trailing characters
            Interrupted
        {not in Vi}
```

---

Or you can use `:silent! %s/\s\+$//` to ignore *all* error messages.