# Vim: glob then yank with newline

Tags: vim, glob

Here is the text:

```
login:johnD
title:John Doe
title:Bob
login:tomS
title:Tom Smith
title:Alice
```

As result, I want to get rid of lines started with "title" without "login" at previous line:

```
login:johnD
title:John Doe
login:tomS
title:Tom Smith
```

First, I try search pattern:

```
/^login.*\ntitle:.*
```

Okay, that highlights me what I want to keep.

The, I try to yank this (with newline) to "a" register:

```
qaq
:g/login.*\ntitle:.*/y A
```

Highlight is also Ok:

```
login:johnD
title:John Doe
login:tomS
title:Tom Smith
```

But, when I check "a" register:

```
:reg a
```

Seems, that is not yanked properly:

```
l  "a ^Jlogin:johnD^Jlogin:tomsS^J
```

Try to paste:

```
"ap
```

Result:

```
login:johnD
login:tomS
```

Next, try not to yank, but to delete pattern (inverted):

```
:g!/login.*\ntitle:.*/d
```

Outcome the same:

```
login:johnD
login:tomS
```

What is wrong with this?
Suspect that something with newline character, but why highlights are showing that all is Ok.

Please help to find this out :)

Comment: Your goal is not clear. Do you want to remove those specific lines from the buffer or do you want to yank them in order to put them elsewhere?

Comment: I tried to yank useful lines, to put them elsewhere.
When I failed with this, I tried to remove excessive lines.

Comment: After some messing around with :global I managed to yank necessary lines properly :qaq + :g/login:/,+1y A + "ap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with 2 commands:

1. `:silent! g/^title/+1s/^title.*//`
   For each line start with title, then do search (start with title) and replace(with empty) to next line(`+1`).
   `:silent!` is to suppress next line not in valid range error.
2. `:g/^$/d`
   delete blank lines

Reference:
[How do I disable error messages when a substitution fails inside a Vim function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093959/how-do-i-disable-error-messages-when-a-substitution-fails-inside-a-vim-function).

[Section 10.3 Add and Subtract](https://vimhelp.org/usr_10.txt.html#10.3)

Comment: Incredible, it works!